How Can I Add an Extensions to a Linux-based Azure App Service?
I am trying to follow the steps in this article to create a certificate for my website in Azure (link is to specific step):
https://www.virtusway.com/en/set-up-ssl-for-an-azure-web-application-using-lets-encrypt.html#lets-encrypt
When I get to the step in question, I do not see an "Extensions" link in my sidebar, nor do I see any way of adding Extensions.  Upon googling, I see some vague references to Extensions not being supported for Linux apps.
Are Extensions not supported in my case, and (if so), why can't I find any reference to that fact?  Is there an alternative for Linux app services?

Extensions option is available only for the apps deployed to windows environment.

You can add or install extensions from SSH for Linux apps.

What you want to install?

The extension is called Let's Encrypt.

I think you can put your first comment as an answer, or maybe combine your first two comments into an answer.

Sure will do it.


I do not see an "Extensions" link in my sidebar, nor do I see any way of adding Extensions.

Extensions option is available only for the Apps deployed in Azure Windows Environment.


If you want to install or add any extensions for Linux Apps you can do it from KUDU => SSH/Bash.



First, Run the below commands to install cerbot in SSH.

apt-get  update
apt-get install certbot



Run apt list --installed command to get the list of installed packages.

Thanks @Jessica Deen for the clear steps.
Refer this blog  to set up  Let's Encrypt SSL Cert for Azure Web App with Linux.
Continue from step 2 to install Let’s Encrypt cert.
